# AWS: how to fix S3 event replacing space with '+' sign in object key names in json

Tags: java, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a lamba function to copy objects from bucket 'A' to bucket 'B', and everything was working fine, until and object with name 'New Text Document.txt' was created in bucket 'A', the json that gets built in S3 event, key as "key": "New+Text+Document.txt".

the spaces got replaced with '+'. I know it is a known issue by seraching on web.
But I am not sure how to fix this and the incoming json itself has a '+' and '+' can be actually in the name of the file. like 'New+Text Document.txt'.

So I cannot blindly have logic to space '+' by ' ' in my lambda function.

Due to this issue, when code tries to find the file in bucket it fails to find it.

Please suggest.

Comment: If you express the name as an HTML url, you could avoid this kind of "collision" : space becomes `%20` and + becomes `%2B` ? You can then convert it back to the real character.

Comment: Thanks @LoneWanderer, but this is a json value that I get from S3 put event.

Comment: Got it, but I think you are screwed up ... If you have to try all combination of `+`and ` ` by opening a file to find out what was the real filename, you can get into trouble ... Can't you just forbid `+` in file names ? sounds violent, but hey ...

Comment: @LoneWanderer there's an entrenched bug in S3's *internal* object key representation, presumably a SOAP holdover.  `%20` **and** `+` in a `PUT` URI are **both** stored internally as the character `+`.   Both symbols in a URI mean ASCII 32... meanwhile, `%2B` is stored as `%2B`, even though no browser would ever escape `+` as `%2B` in a path (that should only happen in the query string).  If you upload a file called `foo+bar` **or** `foo%20bar`, you can actually download the same file as either `foo+bar` or `foo%20bar`.  That is the same object.

Comment: What do have to do If my file is named with a plus sign and a space ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

What I have done to fix this is

```
java.net.URLDecoder.decode(b.getS3().getObject().getKey(), "UTF-8")


{
    "Records": [
        {
            "s3": {
                "object": {
                    "key": "New+Text+Document.txt"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

So now the JSon value, "New+Text+Document.txt" gets converted to New Text Document.txt, correctly.

This has fixed my issue, please suggest if this is very correct solution.
Will there be any corner case that can break my implementation.

Comment: This should be the correct solution.  Unless there are edge/corner cases not handled in an expected/sensible fashion by `java.net.URLDecoder.decode()`, your solution seems exactly correct.

Comment: The problem is that  1. "New+Text+Document.txt" and  2. "New Text Document.txt", and 3. "New Text+Document.txt" will be the same in the event (key: "New+Text+Document.txt"). Your code will be fail on cases 1 and 3.

Comment: same issue in golang, fixed with `url.QueryUnescape(s3key)` from `net/url`

Comment: @ArielAraza Decoding works because the key sent to lambda is already Url encoded. In the case of a file named, "my file with spaces + and plus test.csv", the key sent to lambda is "my+file+with+spaces+%2B+and+plus+test.csv".  (Note the "+" was replaced with "%2B".)

Comment: Great solution, while it's more "Sonar" friendly to use the charset overload instead
`URLDecoder.decode(objectKey, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`

Answer (score 54):

I came across this looking for a solution for a lambda written in python instead of java; "urllib.parse.unquote_plus" worked for me, it properly handled a file with both spaces and + signs:

```
from urllib.parse import unquote_plus
import boto3


bucket = 'testBucket1234'
# uploaded file with name 'foo + bar.txt' for test, s3 Put event passes following encoded object_key
object_key = 'foo %2B bar.txt'
print(object_key)
object_key = unquote_plus(object_key)
print(object_key)

client = boto3.client('s3')
client.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=object_key)
```

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 31):

### NodeJS, Javascript or Typescript

Since we are sharing for other runtimes here is how to do it in NodeJS:

```js
const srcKey = decodeURIComponent(event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, " "));
```

I would say this is an **official solution** since it comes from the [AWS docs here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-tutorial.html#with-s3-tutorial-create-function-code)

Answer (score 6):

I think in Java you should use:

```
getS3().getObject().getUrlDecodedKey()
```

method that returns decoded key, instead of

```
getS3().getObject().getKey()
```

Comment: the problem he's describing and that led me here is that the lambda 'create object' event trigger is what includes the + for space, which means you don't have an object yet because the key (as returned by the event) doesn't match any objects in the bucket.

Comment: I have the exact same problem as the question.  This solution solves the problem using a native method available in the Object - simple and elegant. It returns the key with out the encoding.  The subsequent getObject operation finds the file key successfully and moves the file from Bucket A to Bucket B.

Answer (score 2):

in ASP.Net has UrlDecode. The sample is below.

```
HttpUtility.UrlDecode(s3entity.Object.Key, Encoding.UTF8)
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same issue with special character's, as aws S3 event replacing the special character's as in UrlEncoding. So to resolve the same I have used aws decode API "SdkHttpUtils.urlDecode(String key)" to decode the object key. Hence worked as expected.

You can check below link to get more details about SdkHttpUtils API.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/util/SdkHttpUtils.html#urlDecode-java.lang.String-

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Scott. for me create object event was appending %3 for semicolon : i have to replace it twice to get correct s3 url

**Python** code:

```py
    def lambda_handler(event, context):
    logger.info('Event: %s' % json.dumps(event))
    source_bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key_old = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    key_new = key_old.replace('%3',':')
    key = key_new.replace(':A',':')
    logger.info('key value')
    logger.info(key)
```