# AWS Lambda getting triggered randomly for S3 Uploads

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a lambda trigger setup that fires whenever a new object is added to a S3 bucket. The lambda function is basically a bash script that converts any audio file into a `wav` format using `ffmpeg`.

However, when I'm uploading a file into S3, the Lambda is getting fired before upload completes. The error I get:

```
START RequestId: ef00f261-b051-42ab-85db-c458f39a5635 Version: $LATEST
fatal error: An error occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject operation: Key "incoming/JP2Z+4yklCnHZRQ8JzW5nfsc3MzBKRXQb3Jt6WJf9q3y0+eCWWcvwuzmusxuTDPRQ=" does not exist
END RequestId: ef00f261-b051-42ab-85db-c458f39a5635
```

`incoming/` is my directory in the bucket. I'm uploading a `mp3` file but this is the response I get.

My `function.sh` file

```
function handler () {
  EVENT_DATA=$1
  filename=$(echo $1 | grep incoming | cut -f 2 -d "/" | cut -f 1 -d '"')
  filename_noext=$(echo $filename | cut -f 1 -d '.')
  /var/task/aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/incoming/$filename /tmp/
  /var/task/ffmpeg -i /tmp/$filename -ar 8000 /tmp/$filename_noext.wav
  /var/task/aws s3 cp /tmp/$filename_noext.wav s3://mybucket/outgoing/
  /var/task/aws s3 rm s3://mybucket --recursive --exclude="*" --include="incoming/$filename"
  rm -rf /tmp/$filename
}
```

Can anyone tell what's going on here?

EDIT: The entire pipeline works randomly, If I do it with single file at a time, and retry a couple of times, it works. Is it just me or the S3-Lambda integration is unstable?

Comment: Share the s3 trigger as well, maybe theres an issue with the configuration.

Comment: @AmitBaranes What should I share? It's just a event notification in S3 that calls lambda function, which has prefix and suffix defined

Comment: What's the trigger event ? All object create events? Post? Put?

Comment: @AmitBaranes all objects created

Comment: I have an answer prepared, but need some confirmation.  I believe this is probably only occurring with object keys that happen to include the character `+`.  Please add `echo "$filename"` right after the line `filename=...`.  It may not contain exactly what the error message suggests it contains.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I just got this error message `fatal error: An error occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject operation: Key "incoming/9bn16jpVoYdR" does not exist` This doesn't have any special chars

Comment: Are you, by chance, checking to see if the file exists before you upload it?

Comment: @AnonCoward no checks like that

Comment: @JaskaranSinghPuri okay so you are saying that the problem is not limited to objects with `+` in the object key?

Comment: right, for any upload I do. the lambda seems to being triggered for partial uploads

Answer (score 1):

- I had similar issues a while back and do remember that `s3:ObjectCreated:Put` event is triggered for small files.
- If the file size is large then it triggers `s3:ObjectCreated:CompleteMultipartUpload` event.
- If you are using aws cli to PUT a file in s3 then it does multiparty upload internally.
- As you are copying to another bucket `outgoing` so its worth just for testing to have value `s3:ObjectCreated:*` and see how it behaves.(Make sure you don't end up in a loop of lambda getting triggered because of file getting copied in the same bucket again).

Comment: What's the solution then? Doesn't this make Lambda-S3 integration very unstable? I'm uploading files via `boto3` python. Still same problem

Comment: @amittn your advice is almost always the correct way to configure an event for object creation, but this is a different problem.  Here, the events are firing, but the object isn't behing found.  Using `s3:ObjectCreated:*` instead of `s3:ObjectCreated:Put` solves the problem of events not firing at all due to uploads being performed using the multipart API.

Answer (score 0):

I think that @Michael-sqlbot is correct in that there are two problems being analyzed.

1. The HeadObject 404 Object not found.  I had this one yesterday.  [AWS S3 Event will screw up your objectkey if you have a space in it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44779042/aws-how-to-fix-s3-event-replacing-space-with-sign-in-object-key-names-in-js)
2. Use s3:ObjectCreated:* instead of s3:ObjectCreated:Put because ObjectedCreated will only fire after the multipart put is finished and the object is created.