# AWS Lambda S3 Event Trigger - Object Key Has Pluses Instead of Spaces

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have an AWS Lambda function set up as an event source for an S3 bucket to process newly uploaded PDF files. However, I've noticed that when a file with spaces in its name is uploaded, the event data I receive in the Lambda function has pluses (+) instead of spaces in the key property of the S3 event object.

For example, if I upload a file named "World War.pdf" to my S3 bucket, the Lambda event object shows the key as **"public/World+War.pdf"**:

```
{
    "s3SchemaVersion": "1.0",
    "configurationId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:12345673333312:stack/my-lambda-stack/...",
    "bucket": {
        "name": "mybucket",
        "ownerIdentity": { "principalId": "EXAMPLE" },
        "arn": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"
    },
    "object": {
        "key": "public/World+War.pdf",
        "size": 40656,
        "eTag": "123456789abcdef",
        "sequencer": "1234567890ABCDEF"
    }
}
```

This causes issues when I try to use this key to access the file in my S3 bucket, as the actual file name contains spaces and not pluses.

**What I've tried:**

1. I have considered using decodeURIComponent to convert the + back to spaces, but I'm unsure if this is a reliable solution, or if I'm supposed to handle these keys differently.

   const key = decodeURIComponent(event.Records[0].s3.object.key);
2. I have also looked into the S3 event notification configurations to see if there's a way to receive the key without URL encoding, but found nothing in the AWS documentation.

**Questions:**

1. Why does AWS encode the S3 object key in the event, and is decodeURIComponent the recommended approach to decode it?
2. Is there a configuration in AWS S3 or Lambda that I can set to receive the object key with spaces instead of pluses?

**CloudWatch Error Message:**

```
Error processing and ingesting PDF: public/World+War.pdf. Error: NoSuchKey: The specified key does not exist.
```

Any help or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Yes it's being encoded. Why do you need to convert back to spaces? If your Lambda function just needs to read the object in S3, then the object key with `+` will work.

Comment: Hi Mark, it's because I sent the file name to an SQS queue, and when the queue consumer tries to obtain the file name, it cannot due to the +.

Comment: "when the queue consumer tries to obtain the file name, it cannot due to the +" That doesn't make much sense. What is the actual error?

Comment: Error processing and ingesting PDF: public/World+War.pdf. Error: NoSuchKey: The specified key does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you can find a solution at this link. I had a similar issue and found a solution through this link.
[AWS: how to fix S3 event replacing space with '+' sign in object key names in json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44779042/aws-how-to-fix-s3-event-replacing-space-with-sign-in-object-key-names-in-js)

Answer (score 1):

The solution for this question was two fold:

1. Define the variables before using it
2. Decoding it.

Final solution:

```
const file = decodeURIComponent(event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, " "));
```

Comment: This is the result of a very early design decision in S3 that can't be fixed because so much code accommodates the broken behavior.  Object keys have spaces replaced with `+` like you would find in a query string.  It's very much incorrect to encode this way in the path, but that's now it was done in S3.